# how to change while to do while in java?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

This is my java code can someone help me to change while loop to do-while loop in java please thanks :)

```
 while (round<=25){
        //Player takes turn
        Player currPlayer = players.get(playerIdx);
        int roll = currPlayer.getRoll();;
        //Update the board
        curr = currPlayer.getNextposition();
        System.out.printf("%s\n",currPlayer.getName());
        System.out.printf("Old: %d\n",currPlayer.getCurrposition());
        System.out.printf("Dice: %d\n",currPlayer.getRoll());
        System.out.printf("New: %d\n",currPlayer.getNextposition());
        if(curr==100) {
            menu=-1;
            break;
        }
```

Are the code like this? I try :

```
do{
    Player currPlayer = players.get(playerIdx);
    int roll = currPlayer.getRoll();;

    curr = currPlayer.getNextposition();
    System.out.printf("%s\n",currPlayer.getName());
    System.out.printf("Old: %d\n",currPlayer.getCurrposition());
    System.out.printf("Dice: %d\n",currPlayer.getRoll());
    System.out.printf("New: %d\n",currPlayer.getNextposition());

            if(curr==100) {
                menu=-1;
                break;
            }while (round<=25)
```

Comment: First of all in either case you need to initialize your `round=0` variable before entering the loop, and then in the loop, you should increment it (I'm assuming this because your loop condition is round <= 25). In the code you paste you do nothing with `round` variable. So, currently assuming round = 0 at start, this is an infinite loop with only exit condition of curr==100, so might as well be `while(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

just insert `while(...)` at the end

```
do {
    //Player takes turn
    Player currPlayer = players.get(playerIdx);
    int roll = currPlayer.getRoll();;
    //Update the board
    curr = currPlayer.getNextposition();
    System.out.printf("%s\n",currPlayer.getName());
    System.out.printf("Old: %d\n",currPlayer.getCurrposition());
    System.out.printf("Dice: %d\n",currPlayer.getRoll());
    System.out.printf("New: %d\n",currPlayer.getNextposition());
    if(curr==100) {
        menu=-1;
        break;
    } 
} while (round <= 25);
```

Comment: `if (curr==100) {...} while (round<=25)` looks strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
Player currPlayer = players.get(playerIdx);
int roll = currPlayer.getRoll();;

curr = currPlayer.getNextposition();
System.out.printf("%s\n",currPlayer.getName());
System.out.printf("Old: %d\n",currPlayer.getCurrposition());
System.out.printf("Dice: %d\n",currPlayer.getRoll());
System.out.printf("New: %d\n",currPlayer.getNextposition());
if(curr==100) {
    menu=-1;
    break;
}
```

}while (round < 25)

Comment: Please explain why your code works (and what the major difference is compared to the OPs try).

Also, why does everyone assume that round will be <=25 in the beginning?